# Entity Framework Migrations: Prevent dropping column or table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

If `EF migration` decides to rename a `column` (or a `table`), it fulfills this by dropping the (old) column and then adding a column with the new name. This clearly leads to data loss.

Is there any way to prevent `EF migration` from dropping a column and force it to use `RenameColumn` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I didn't find a clear and straightforward solution.

**My solution** is *hiding* `DbMigration` class which every migration that was generated using code-based migration is derived from. I do this by introducing a new class with the same name (`DbMigration`). Then I put it inside the same assembly and same namespace where code files reside. This way, any reference of code files to the original `DbMigration` resolves to the new `DbMigration` type. Then, I can switch dropping a column ON or Off:

```
namespace MyProject.DAL.Migrations
{
   
    /// <summary>
    /// Customized DbMigration which protects columns to be dropped accidentally
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class DbMigration : global::System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration
    {
        public bool AlloDropColumn { get; set; }
        protected internal new void DropColumn(string table, string name, object anonymousArguments = null)
        {
            if (!AlloDropColumn)
                throw new Exception("MyProject: Dropping a column while updating database is prohibited. If you really want to drop column(s), set property 'AllowDropColumn' true.");
        }
    }
}
```

And in a code file:

```
public partial class _1 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AlloDropColumn = true; // To allow column drop
            AddColumn("driver.TruckDriver", "FullName2", c => c.String());
            DropColumn("driver.TruckDriver", "FullName");
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            AddColumn("driver.TruckDriver", "FullName", c => c.String());
            DropColumn("driver.TruckDriver", "FullName2");
        }
    }
```